# Add entity using factory repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext

I have the interface.

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   void Add(T entity);
   void Update(T entity);
   void Delete(T entity);
   void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
```

Then

```
 public interface ICatRepository : IRepository<Cat>
 {
 }
```

Also I have the base class.

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext dataContext;
    protected readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    protected DbContext DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }
    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Add(entity);           
    }
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Attach(entity);
        dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    } 
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Remove(entity);           
    }
    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> objects = dbset.Where<T>(filter).AsEnumerable();
        foreach (T obj in objects)
           dbset.Remove(obj);
    }
```

Now I have the implementation class.

```
 class CatRepository : RepositoryBase<Cat>, ICatRepository
 {
    public CatRepository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory) : base(databaseFactory)
    {

    }

    public void Add(Cat entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(Cat entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(Expression<Func<Cat, bool>> filter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

My entity framework knowledge is little rusty. Not sure how to implement Add, Delete methods etc. Please give me a hint. Code snippet is warmly welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure how to implement Add, Delete methods

They are already implemented in RepositoryBase.

Comment: Hey, how stupid I am...Do I have to add `SaveChanges()` in the methods?

Comment: That depends on how you handle Units of Work.  An outer scope may control the DbContext lifecycle, transactions and SaveChanges().

Answer (score 0):

Your `CatRepository` inherits from your generic `RepositoryBase` which has its generic parameter set to your `Cat` domain entities. Your `Add` and `Delete` is already implemented in your `RepositoryBase` class.

The purpose of generic repository is to have common logic grouped together, like `Add()`, `Delete()`, `AddRange()`, `DeleteRange()`, and the purpose of your `CatRepository` is to have extremely specific implementation like `GetNaughtiestCat()` method. If you don't have these implementations, you could still use the `GenericRepository` with the generic parameter set to `Cat`, you need to remove the `abstract` keyword.